# animate opacity from 0 to 1 and than back

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to animate opacity( and translate value ) from 0 to 1 and than back to 0, when the class is removed. The opacity animates nicely to 1, but it does not animate back to 0. Instead it just jumps. See this pen to see my problem in action. What am I missing here?

https://codepen.io/timsim/pen/QvppGz

Code:

```
.cp-active {
    transform: translateY(50px) !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

#cp {
    background-color:red;
    top: -30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 85%;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: black;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;

    height:100px;
   width:100px;
}

$("body").on("click", function(){

    if ($("#cp").hasClass("cp-active")){
        $("#cp").removeClass("cp-active")
    }else{
        $("#cp").addClass("cp-active")
    }

});
```

Comment: add your `transition` to `.cp-active`

Comment: Your code is chrome-safari only compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey check out this fiddle.
Your transition need to be on ALL and not only on TRANSFORM
This:

```
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

instead of:

```
transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out
```

because you are animating opacity as well.

Also i switched your jQuery fnction. It's simpler now

```js
$("body").on("click", function() {
  $("#cp").toggleClass("cp-active");
});
```

```css
#cp.cp-active {
  transform: translateY(50px);
  opacity: 1;
}

#cp {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cp">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Traver solution above is very good. here's another one using just JQ ( without any other css except general #cp styles )

```js
    $("body").on("click", function(){


            if ($("#cp").hasClass("isVisible")){
                $("#cp").animate({
                  'top':'-50',
                  "opacity":"0"
                },500).removeClass("isVisible")
            }else{
                $("#cp").animate({
                  'top':'0',
                  "opacity":"1"
                },500).addClass("isVisible")
            }
        
    });
```

```css
    body {
     height:100vh;
    }
    #cp {
      background-color:red;
      position: relative;
   top:-50px;
      width: 85%;
      margin: auto;
      box-shadow: none;
      border-color: black;
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
      opacity:0;
      height:100px;
      width:100px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cp"></div>
```